# Formatting A Fixed Width Field SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to format a payment amount into a 12 character fixed width field. The fixed width is right justified, left zero filled, and cannot have decimal point (although the last two characters in the field are assumed as decimals). Also, ff the payment amount is negative, there must be a negative sign in the first character in the fixed width field. For example, if payment amount is -125.98, the fixed width field should read -00000012598

Here is the code I have tried.

```
    CASE WHEN TransactionAmount >= 0 THEN RIGHT('000000000000' + CAST(CAST(ROUND(TransactionAmount*100, 0) AS INT) AS VARCHAR), 12)
         ELSE RIGHT('00000000000-' + CAST(REPLACE(CAST(ROUND(TransactionAmount*100, 0) AS INT),'-','') AS VARCHAR), 12)
    END
```

The field 'TransactionAmount' is extracted as such.

```
TransactionAmount = PAY.Amount
```

Obviously, the negative sign will be in the wrong position. Any idea how to always have it as the first character in the field if the amount is negative?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do formatting in the DB layer?

Comment: I am not sure what a DB layer is, but maybe my edit to my question answers yours. The query I am writing extracts all the data in an inner query, and then does formatting in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Format function and get the result as given below. I am removing decimal place first and followed by removing extra 0 with negative sign, to keep the fixed width as 12 characters.

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT(transactionamount, '0000000000.00'),'.',''),'-0','-') as formattedamount
    fROM
    (VALUES(-128.58)) AS T(TransactionAmount)
```

> -00000012858